# Pinging computers on local network: destination host unreachable

Tags: networking

I have two ubuntu computers on a local network and neither one of them can ping each other. Every time I try I get the "destination host unreachable" error message. Both computers are able to access the internet with any problems.

I have a ActionTech v1000h router from Telus. I've been in touch with one of their customer representatives and they said that there should't be any reason why two devices cannot ping each other on the network.

I'm totally at a loss, do any of you guys have any ideas?

**Computer 1:**

ifconfig -a

```
lo        Link encap:Local Loopback  
          inet addr:127.0.0.1  Mask:255.0.0.0
          inet6 addr: ::1/128 Scope:Host
          UP LOOPBACK RUNNING  MTU:65536  Metric:1
          RX packets:10084 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
          TX packets:10084 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
          collisions:0 txqueuelen:0 
          RX bytes:797420 (797.4 KB)  TX bytes:797420 (797.4 KB)

wlan0     Link encap:Ethernet  HWaddr c4:85:08:77:d3:f5  
          inet addr:192.168.1.77  Bcast:192.168.1.255  Mask:255.255.255.0
          inet6 addr: fe80::c685:8ff:fe77:d3f5/64 Scope:Link
          UP BROADCAST RUNNING MULTICAST  MTU:1500  Metric:1
          RX packets:373068 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
          TX packets:380158 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
          collisions:0 txqueuelen:1000 
          RX bytes:103445020 (103.4 MB)  TX bytes:112630337 (112.6 MB)
```

route -n

```
Kernel IP routing table
Destination     Gateway         Genmask         Flags Metric Ref    Use Iface
0.0.0.0         192.168.1.254   0.0.0.0         UG    0      0        0 wlan0
169.254.0.0     0.0.0.0         255.255.0.0     U     1000   0        0 wlan0
192.168.1.0     0.0.0.0         255.255.255.0   U     9      0        0 wlan0
```

sudo iptables -L

```
Chain INPUT (policy ACCEPT)
target     prot opt source               destination         

Chain FORWARD (policy ACCEPT)
target     prot opt source               destination         

Chain OUTPUT (policy ACCEPT)
target     prot opt source               destination
```

**Computer 2:**

ifconfig -a

```
etho0     Link encap:Ethernet HWaddr 00:24:8c:ae:f6:91
          UP BROADCAST MULTICAST MTU:1500 Metric:1
          RX packets:0 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
          TX packets:0 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:2
          collisions:0 txqueuelen:1000
          RX bytes:0 (0.0 B) TX bytes:0 (0.0 B)

lo        Link encap:Local Loopback  
          inet addr:127.0.0.1  Mask:255.0.0.0
          inet6 addr: ::1/128 Scope:Host
          UP LOOPBACK RUNNING  MTU:65536  Metric:1
          RX packets:110 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
          TX packets:110 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
          collisions:0 txqueuelen:0 
          RX bytes:8414 (8.4 KB)  TX bytes:8414 (8.4 KB)

wlan0     Link encap:Ethernet  HWaddr 00:22:43:9b:7b:64  
          inet addr:192.168.1.2  Bcast:192.168.1.255  Mask:255.255.255.0
          inet6 addr: fe80::222:43ff:fe9b:7b64/64 Scope:Link
          UP BROADCAST RUNNING MULTICAST  MTU:1500  Metric:1
          RX packets:252 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
          TX packets:435 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
          collisions:0 txqueuelen:1000 
          RX bytes:123143 (123.1 KB)  TX bytes:65828 (65.8 KB)
```

route -n

```
Kernel IP routing table
Destination     Gateway         Genmask         Flags Metric Ref    Use Iface
0.0.0.0         192.168.1.254   0.0.0.0         UG    0      0        0 wlan0
192.168.1.0     0.0.0.0         255.255.255.0   U     9      0        0 wlan0
```

sudo iptables -L

```
Chain INPUT (policy ACCEPT)
target     prot opt source               destination         

Chain FORWARD (policy ACCEPT)
target     prot opt source               destination         

Chain OUTPUT (policy ACCEPT)
target     prot opt source               destination
```

**Edit:** Example of the error when computer 1 tries to ping computer 2:

ping 192.168.1.2

```
PING 192.168.1.2 (192.168.1.2) 56(84) bytes of data.
From 192.168.1.77 icmp_seq=1 Destination Host Unreachable
From 192.168.1.77 icmp_seq=2 Destination Host Unreachable
From 192.168.1.77 icmp_seq=3 Destination Host Unreachable
From 192.168.1.77 icmp_seq=4 Destination Host Unreachable
From 192.168.1.77 icmp_seq=5 Destination Host Unreachable
From 192.168.1.77 icmp_seq=6 Destination Host Unreachable
^C
--- 192.168.1.2 ping statistics ---
7 packets transmitted, 0 received, +6 errors, 100% packet loss, time 6031ms
pipe 3
```

**Edit 2:** `arp -a` of both computers

Computer 1:

```
? (192.168.1.254) at 20:76:00:f5:3b:70 [ether] on wlan0
```

Computer 2:

```
? (192.168.1.254) at 20:76:00:f5:3b:70 [ether] on wlan0
? (192.168.1.77) at <incomplete> on wlan0
```

**Edit 3:** `nmap -sn 192.168.1.0/24` on computer 2

```
Starting Nmap 6.40 ( http://nmap.org ) at 2014-05-07 21:14 PDT
Nmap scan report for 192.168.1.2
Host is up (0.00024s latency).
Nmap done: 256 IP addresses (1 host up) scanned in 3.30 seconds
```

**Edit 4:** The tcpdump logs of both computers while the first ping 192.168.1.254 and then each other:

Computer 1:

```
tcpdump: verbose output suppressed, use -v or -vv for full protocol decode
listening on wlan0, link-type EN10MB (Ethernet), capture size 65535 bytes
22:45:01.661300 ARP, Request who-has 192.168.1.2 tell 192.168.1.77, length 28
22:45:02.659393 ARP, Request who-has 192.168.1.2 tell 192.168.1.77, length 28
22:45:03.659394 ARP, Request who-has 192.168.1.2 tell 192.168.1.77, length 28
22:45:04.676872 ARP, Request who-has 192.168.1.2 tell 192.168.1.77, length 28
22:45:05.675391 ARP, Request who-has 192.168.1.2 tell 192.168.1.77, length 28
22:45:06.675396 ARP, Request who-has 192.168.1.2 tell 192.168.1.77, length 28
22:45:07.692825 ARP, Request who-has 192.168.1.2 tell 192.168.1.77, length 28
22:45:48.379058 ARP, Request who-has 192.168.1.77 tell 192.168.1.254, length 28
22:45:48.379108 ARP, Reply 192.168.1.77 is-at c4:85:08:77:d3:f5, length 28
22:45:54.419388 ARP, Request who-has 192.168.1.254 tell 192.168.1.77, length 28
22:45:54.420875 ARP, Reply 192.168.1.254 is-at 20:76:00:f5:3b:70, length 28
```

Computer 2:

```
reading from file pc2.pcap, link-type EN10MB (Ethernet)
22:44:43.538367 ARP, Request who-has 192.168.1.254 tell 192.168.1.2, length 28
22:44:43.676705 ARP, Reply 192.168.1.254 is-at 20:76:00:f5:3b:70 (oui Unknown), length 28
22:45:02.107935 ARP, Request who-has 192.168.1.254 tell 192.168.1.2, length 28
22:45:02.107951 ARP, Reply 192.168.1.254 is-at 20:76:00:f5:3b:70 (oui Unknown), length 28
22:45:06.780619 ARP, Request who-has 192.168.1.77 tell 192.168.1.2, length 28
22:45:07.778419 ARP, Request who-has 192.168.1.77 tell 192.168.1.2, length 28
22:45:08.778419 ARP, Request who-has 192.168.1.77 tell 192.168.1.2, length 28
22:45:09.796214 ARP, Request who-has 192.168.1.77 tell 192.168.1.2, length 28
```

**Edit 5:** Setup static ips for both computers etho0 and connected them with an internet cable. Both computers can definitely ping each other through the ethernet cable! `ifconfig -a` eth0 results:

Computer 1:

```
eth0      Link encap:Ethernet  HWaddr 68:68:68:00:62:a4  
          inet addr:192.168.1.10  Bcast:192.168.1.255  Mask:255.255.255.0
          inet6 addr: fe80::6a68:68ff:fe00:62a4/64 Scope:Link
          UP BROADCAST RUNNING MULTICAST  MTU:1500  Metric:1
          RX packets:15 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
          TX packets:0 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
          collisions:0 txqueuelen:1000 
          RX bytes:4060 (4.0 KB)  TX bytes:7629 (7.6 KB)
```

Computer 2:

```
eth0      Link encap:Ethernet  HWaddr 00:24:8c:ae:f6:91  
          inet addr:192.168.1.20  Bcast:192.168.1.255  Mask:255.255.255.0
          inet6 addr: fe80::224:8cff:feae:f691/64 Scope:Link
          UP BROADCAST RUNNING MULTICAST  MTU:1500  Metric:1
          RX packets:250 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
          TX packets:130 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:3
          collisions:0 txqueuelen:1000 
          RX bytes:26501 (26.5 KB)  TX bytes:20897 (20.8 KB)
```

Comment: How are you pinging them? IP? Hostname?

Comment: Who is telling you "destination host unreachable" - your local adapter or something else? Please provide copy/paste of the ping commands and their output.

Comment: I am pinging them using their IP addresses. I've added an edit to the original post detailing the command I'm using and the error message.

Comment: Are you maybe blocking ping in your router's settings?

Comment: I don't believe so, I've combed through the router's settings for a couple of hours. I also talked to a telus representative and he didn't give me any indication that that could be the problem.

Comment: **icmp** is the protocol which use to handle/allow ping requests. I've seen some router having the capability to disable/enable. I'm not too sure that's the reason but worth checking the router once again. :)

Comment: I've double checked. I don't see any option on the router's configuration pages.

Comment: I see both PCs are on WiFi. Check if there's an option called "AP isolation" in your router and disable it. AP isolation will prevent clients on WiFi from reaching eachother.

Comment: I don't see an option called "AP isolation" or any option on any of the router's configuration pages that would block my devices from communicating with each other.

Comment: FWIW, I had a similar problem with a Telus-branded ActionTech v1000h (in its default configuration).  I upgraded the firmware from 31.121L.13 to 31.122L.13 and it magically disappeared....

Answer (score 6):

ping gateway from both computers `ping 192.168.1.254`
then try to ping comp1 to compt2 and comp2 to comp1
then post results of `arp -a` from BOTH boxes

**Edit**

Interesting, something is blocking traffic

run `sudo tcpdump -ni wlan0 arp` in one window on both computers and then try pinging each other and the gateway from another window on both again and post results

**Edit2**

So far that shows that comp1 is doing what it's suppose to sending arp request (asking for comp2s etherner address) but not getting an arp reply (hearing anything back). Need to see the tcpdump from PC2 to see the full picture. Either run the screen command or do this on PC1 `sudo tcpdump -w pc1.pcap -ni wlan0 arp &` and on PC2 `sudo tcpdump -w pc2.pcap -ni wlan0 arp &`   **&** should throw it in the background and give you your prompt back for pings. After pings fail bring the jobs back to foreground with `fg %1` stop it `ctrl+c` and read the written files with `sudo tcpdump -r pc1/2.pcap`

**Edit3**
PCs are doing what they're suppose to, putting ARPs out but they're not getting through which points to the router. Maybe a disable firewall setting, doubt it supports VLANs? Kinda wish you let it run a bit longer at **22:45:48.379058** your router sent its own ARP request when it was looking for PC1 `22:45:48.379058 ARP, Request who-has 192.168.1.77 tell 192.168.1.254, length 28` both PCs should've seen it, we can see that PC1 saw it and replied with its IP but cant tell if PC2 got it since since you stopped it stop just short at **22:45:09.796214**. Assuming you're clocks are synced with NTP that is.

**Edit4**

See that it's still not resolved. Didn't see that you have eth adapters on both PCs. Can you hardwire into the router on eth instead of wlan and see if you can ping then? Or get another router? Or make a hotspot on the phone connect both PCs and try to ping? Also, surprised to see that you were able to connect two PCs together and ping each other did you use a crossover cable?

Comment: Both computers can ping 192.168.1.254 without any problems and neither computer can successfully ping the other, getting the error message I posted above. I've added a second edit to the original post with the results of `arp -a~ on both computers.

Comment: Computer 2 only has one window so I don't know how to get it to use tcdump and ping computer 1 at the same time. I've added the results of running tcdump on computer 1 in the fourth edit of the original post.

Comment: The `screen` command, with Ctrl-A then c to create a new window could be helpful. Ctrl-A then <Space> goes forward a window, Ctrl-A then <Backspace> goes back one, so that you can switch between them.

Comment: I have redone the fourth edit. Both computers were running tcpdump and both computers were trying to ping 192.168.1.254 and then each other. Thank you for walking me through that!

Answer (score 1):

My fist response when I see something weird like this is to install wireshark.

Then make it so you have permission to use it as non-root:

```
sudo dpkg-reconfigure wireshark-common
```

Choose the "yes" option.

```
usermod -a -G wireshark your-user-name
```

Logout and log back in to pick up the new group membership and you can now run capture packets as a non-root user.

Then run wireshark on the machine, selecting the interface connected to the network. Try to minimize traffic other than your testing to make interpreting the results easier.

If you run wireshark on one machine, and then try to ping from another, you *should* see something on the machine running wireshark that says something along the lines of "Who has <ip you're trying to ping>". If you get that, then the computer trying to ping is having it's request recieved by the wireshark computer. Hopefully, you should also see in wireshark something along the lines of "<ip address you're trying to ping> is at <mac address>". If you do, then the wireshark computer is responding. If that is the case, then try running wireshark on the computer pinging and see if you can see the "<ip address you're trying to ping> is at <mac address>" response on the pinging computer.

I apologize if this is too low level and goes over your head. This method does get deep into the details. But being able to see what is actually happening on the network tends to make problems a lot more obvious.

Comment: I've installed wireshark on computer 2 as per your instructions. Unfortunately, computer 2 can't open wireshark's display so I've also installed tshark, is that ok? I used the command `tshark -i wlan0` and don't see any results while computer 1 is trying to ping computer 2.

Comment: tshark should be fine, I just said wireshark because I though the GUI would make it easier :)  What I would try considering the results is doing the reverse and see if you can see anything on computer 1 using (wire/t)shark and pinging from computer2. If that also doesn't show anything ARP or ICMP, I would see if you can find anything in the router's wireless pages about "Client Isolation" or something along those lines. If you find it, you want it off.

Comment: I installed wireshark on computer 1. Computer 1 is my personal laptop and it has a lot of traffic so I'm not going to post the full results here. I can see it broadcast `Who has 192.168.1.2? Tell 192.168.1.77` but it never receives a response. The router I'm using doesn't have client isolation enabled as per their faq: http://www.actiontec.com/products/faqs.php?pid=191#q25

Answer (score 1):

Try to connect directly your two computers each other with an ethernet cable, setting to both a fixed IP address (ex A : 192.168.1.10, B : 192.168.1.20) and try to ping again.

Then you will know very quickly if the problem comes from your router, or your computers.

Comment: I set computer 1 eth0 to a fixed IP of 192.168.1.10. I only have a terminal with computer 2 so I couldn't use the same method as with computer 1; how do you fix the ip in a terminal? In any case, I fixed the eth0 ip of computer 1, connected them both with an ethernet cable and used computer 2 to ping computer 1. No luck.

Comment: See here to change the IP address of computer B using command line : http://askubuntu.com/questions/342705/how-to-set-a-static-ip-address

Comment: Well, I'd say is `ping localhost` or `ping 127.0.0.1` which tells you whether the network interface is up. That means both your PC's are able to handle request if I'm not mistaken.

Comment: Thanks for all your help! After doing what you suggested, the computers can ping each other over the ethernet cable. I've added additional information in the fifth edit of my original post. Does this mean that the problem is definitely with the router?

Answer (score 1):

The problem seems to be in your network. Not in the linux machines themselves.
I'd say it is your wireless router/access point that is playing tricks with you.

- Since you can reach the Internet from both hosts, they can get the default gateways MAC through an ARP request.
- They don't get each others ARP requests or replies.
- They (proven on computer1) get the routers ARP request.

This indicates that your router/AP swallows the ARP requests, and without ARP functioning, they don't know the MAC of the other one, and thus they cannot talk Ethernet with each other.

**Try have the router DHCP assign the addresses** instead of statically assigning them yourself.

Or add them **statically to your ARP cache** to see if that helps.

On Computer1:

```
arp -s 192.168.1.2 00:22:43:9b:7b:64
```

On Computer2:

```
arp -a 192.168.1.77 c4:85:08:77:d3:f5
```

Answer (score 1):

I had the same symptoms with my LAN (ubuntu machines only). It happened since we got a new router. It's one of those dual band ones. Couldn't make sense of the problem, until I thought may be one "band"  is totally disjoint from the other. Should be easy to test, I disconnected one machine from wifi and reconnected it (to the same SSID), and what do you know, I got lucky (is it a 50-50 chance?) and it appeared on the lan of the other machine and I can now ping and log-into it! The "nmap" above  gave me the clue. Thanks for the idea.

Comment: Please don't add 'thanks' as answers. Invest some time in the site and you will gain sufficient [privileges](http://askubuntu.com/privileges) to upvote answers you like, which is the Ask Ubuntu way of saying thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Go through your router's configuration and see if local network firewall(s) aren't up. Some routers, by default, isolate connected devices from each other.

You can also use `nmap`:

```
$ nmap -sn 192.168.1.0/24
```

See if this comes up with anything.

Comment: I've gone through my router's configuration pages and I don't believe there are any local network firewalls set up. I also talked to a customer representative and he didn't mention any. I've added a third edit to the original post with the results of `nmap` on computer 2.

Answer (score 0):

Something is messed up with your routing table but I can't see anything wrong with it. "Host unreachable" means that the kernel can't decide which adapter to use to send the packet so it gives up and drops the packet.

The Metric for your local network is 9. That ought to be 0 or 1. However the Linux kernel is rumoured to ignore the metric.

I would try to add a route to the specific host. Try this on Computer 1:

`route add -host 192.168.1.2 metric 0 dev wlan0`

Also try removing the route to 169.254.0.0 and see if that will help. It is unlikely but you never know.

## EDIT

You don't have VPN running, do you? Cisco VPN is known to interfere with the local network connections.

Comment: I removed the route to 169.254.0.0 from computer 1. I also added a route to 192.168.1.2 to computer 1. The corresponding new route in the `route -n` table is: `192.168.1.2 0.0.0.0 255.255.255.255 UH 0 0 0 wlan0`

Comment: Nope, I don't believe I have a VPN on running.

Answer (score 0):

All your packets from **Computer 1** and **Computer 2** are routed to **wlan0** on each localhost, but neither wireless interface is associated with a wireless network.

Did you assign the IP addresses manually? They should be provided, via DHCP, by the router, as part of the association/authentication setup.

Do `sudo iwlist wlan0 scan` on each computer to see the wireless networks available to each computer. One of them should be your router. Is the router configured with an ESSID (wireless network name) that differs from the default?

What sort of encryption is the router configured for/capable of? Choices are None (very very bad), WEP (very bad), WPA(bad) and WPA2(best available for now). All 3 systems must agree on a common encryption.

Once all that is straightened out, **Computer 1** should be able to wirelessly connect to the router, get an IP address from it (along with other networking info like the default gateway, MTU). Be able to `ping` the router.

Repeat for **Computer 2**.

Then, and only then, may you truly `ping`, if the router allows local address routing.

Comment: From what I can tell, the router uses `WPA / WPA2` security with a `WPA or WPA2 - Personal` WPA type. The ESSID is configured to be different than the default. Both computers can find the routers with the `sudo iwlist wlan0 scan` command. Both computers can ping the router. Computer 1 has a dynamic IP and computer 2 has a fixed IP. Neither computer can ping the other.

Comment: I use `NetworkManager` to manage my wifi connections and passwords, and `iwconfig` shows:  

`$ iwconfig wlan0  
wlan0     IEEE 802.11bg  ESSID:"Fairfield"    
          Mode:Managed  Frequency:2.422 GHz  Access Point: 14:D6:4D:2D:5F:AE     
          Bit Rate=54 Mb/s   Tx-Power=20 dBm   
          Retry  long limit:7   RTS thr:off   Fragment thr:off    
          Power Management:off    
          Link Quality=70/70  Signal level=-40 dBm      
          Rx invalid nwid:0  Rx invalid crypt:0  Rx Invalid frag:0  
          Tx excessive retries:0  Invalid misc:37 Missed beacon:0  `

Answer (score 0):

Check if your wlan router AP has an isolation option (enable AP Isolation) disable it.