# Ssh: No route to host

Tags: 14.04

I have two laptops having Ubuntu 14.04 LTS. I have connected both of them to same wireless network.Now I have installed ssh server on Ubuntu.Now I am trying to access other laptop's ( say B) desktop but error is coming like

```
    Ssh:connect to host 192.168.0.102 port 22: No route to host
```

I am using following command

```
    ssh user@192.168.0.102
```

The following is the output for ifconfig

```
     eth0      Link encap:Ethernet  HWaddr 28:92:4a:1e:eb:ed  
      UP BROADCAST MULTICAST  MTU:1500  Metric:1
      RX packets:0 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
      TX packets:0 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
      collisions:0 txqueuelen:1000 
      RX bytes:0 (0.0 B)  TX bytes:0 (0.0 B)

     lo        Link encap:Local Loopback  
      inet addr:127.0.0.1  Mask:255.0.0.0
      inet6 addr: ::1/128 Scope:Host
      UP LOOPBACK RUNNING  MTU:65536  Metric:1
      RX packets:614 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
      TX packets:614 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
      collisions:0 txqueuelen:0 
      RX bytes:53218 (53.2 KB)  TX bytes:53218 (53.2 KB)

      wlan0     Link encap:Ethernet  HWaddr 08:3e:8e:0e:4f:4b  
      inet addr:192.168.0.100  Bcast:192.168.0.255  Mask:255.255.255.0
      inet6 addr: fe80::a3e:8eff:fe0e:4f4b/64 Scope:Link
      UP BROADCAST RUNNING MULTICAST  MTU:1500  Metric:1
      RX packets:1412 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:13931
      TX packets:1931 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
      collisions:0 txqueuelen:1000 
      RX bytes:557138 (557.1 KB)  TX bytes:240606 (240.6 KB)
      Interrupt:17
```

The following happens when I do ping

```
      PING 192.168.0.102 (192.168.0.102) 56(84) bytes of data.
      From 192.168.0.100 icmp_seq=9 Destination Host Unreachable
      From 192.168.0.100 icmp_seq=10 Destination Host Unreachable
      From 192.168.0.100 icmp_seq=11 Destination Host Unreachable
      From 192.168.0.100 icmp_seq=12 Destination Host Unreachable
      From 192.168.0.100 icmp_seq=13 Destination Host Unreachable
      From 192.168.0.100 icmp_seq=14 Destination Host Unreachable
      From 192.168.0.100 icmp_seq=15 Destination Host Unreachable
      From 192.168.0.100 icmp_seq=16 Destination Host Unreachable
      From 192.168.0.100 icmp_seq=17 Destination Host Unreachable
      From 192.168.0.100 icmp_seq=18 Destination Host Unreachable
      From 192.168.0.100 icmp_seq=19 Destination Host Unreachable
      From 192.168.0.100 icmp_seq=20 Destination Host Unreachable
      From 192.168.0.100 icmp_seq=21 Destination Host Unreachable
      From 192.168.0.100 icmp_seq=22 Destination Host Unreachable
      From 192.168.0.100 icmp_seq=23 Destination Host Unreachable
      From 192.168.0.100 icmp_seq=24 Destination Host Unreachable
      From 192.168.0.100 icmp_seq=25 Destination Host Unreachable
      From 192.168.0.100 icmp_seq=26 Destination Host Unreachable
      From 192.168.0.100 icmp_seq=27 Destination Host Unreachable
      From 192.168.0.100 icmp_seq=28 Destination Host Unreachable
      From 192.168.0.100 icmp_seq=29 Destination Host Unreachable
      From 192.168.0.100 icmp_seq=30 Destination Host Unreachable
      From 192.168.0.100 icmp_seq=31 Destination Host Unreachable
      From 192.168.0.100 icmp_seq=32 Destination Host Unreachable
      and so on.....
```

Output of netstat -rn

```
      Kernel IP routing table
      Destination     Gateway         Genmask         Flags   MSS Window  irtt Iface
      0.0.0.0         192.168.0.1     0.0.0.0         UG        0 0          0 wlan0
      192.168.0.0     0.0.0.0         255.255.255.0   U         0 0          0 wlan0
```

Comment: can you ping the other machine?

Comment: What's your `ifconfig` command output?

Comment: @Mehdi I did pin. Please see the edited question

Comment: @Mahdi a  I did ifconfig. Please see the edited question

Comment: Test what is said here: http://askubuntu.com/questions/462643/pinging-computers-on-local-network-destination-host-unreachable

Comment: "Destination Host Unreachable" suggests a route issue. Could you give the output of netstat -rn ?

Comment: @monitor35  now I am able to ping other system.But new problem is that when I enter password,after running the command ssh@192.168.0.102,it says PERMISSION DENIED,please try again

Comment: Which user you used  to connect ? root ?!

Comment: @monitor35 Yes i am logging on root

Comment: check the parameter PermitRootLogin in the file /etc/ssh/sshd_config . It must be yes so : PermitRootLogin yes . Exit and reload the service /etc/init.d/ssh reload

Comment: @monitor35 I did what u said but my problem was not solved

Answer (score 1):

Maybe you need to disable the firewall ... You can check if the ssh-server is working and listening the network by using nmap (need to install it first):

```
apt-get install nmap -y

nmap -p22 192.168.0.102
```

You need to see something like that which indicate that the port 22 (ssh port) is  open:

```
root@srkv12b3:/home/monitor# nmap  -p22 192.168.19.4
Starting Nmap 7.01 ( https://nmap.org ) at 2016-04-06 11:08 CEST
Nmap scan report for 192.168.19.4
Host is up (0.000033s latency).
PORT   STATE SERVICE
22/tcp open  ssh

Nmap done: 1 IP address (1 host up) scanned in 5.79 seconds
```

Comment: Following output i got: Starting Nmap 6.40 ( http://nmap.org ) at 2016-04-06 15:16 IST
Note: Host seems down. If it is really up, but blocking our ping probes, try -Pn
Nmap done: 1 IP address (0 hosts up) scanned in 0.44 seconds