# SSH no route to host

Tags: 16.04, ssh

I am trying to SSH into a Raspberry Pi with Ubuntu 16 OS. However, whenever I try to SSH into it, I get this message.

````
ssh: connect to host 192.168.0.32 port 22: No route to host```
````

So I tried to run `nmap` and I get this error message:

```
Error #486: Your port specifications are illegal.  Example of proper form: "-100,200-1024,T:3000-4000,U:60000-"
QUITTING!
```

After looking around online I am still none the wiser as to what this means or how to fix it

I also can not ping the Raspberry Pi from my computer or ping my computer from the Raspberry Pi.

Comment: seems very likely that there is a network problem on the raspberry pi.   I have not used, but would suggest that you debug and see what driver/hardware for the network you see on pi.

Comment: Can you do a ssh -vv <your arguments> ?

Comment: describe your local area network (LAN). Is there a router? is there a switch, perhaps via the same router? What is the sub-net for LAN side of the router, if there is one? How did the raspberry pi get its IP address? Was it via DHCP from the router? Is everything on the same sub-net?

Comment: sorry im fairly new to this, im guessing <your arguments> is the ip of the host. I did that and it says "Bad tun device '192.168.0.32'"

Comment: First check if you have UFW running on the pi `sudo ufw status verbose` Also make sure you don't have AP isolation set on your local network (assuming you are working on your local network).

Comment: Additionally, run `hostname -I | awk '{print $1}'` on your pi to verify the IP is correct. Then, check to see that the router also shows the same IP is assigned to your raspberry pi.

Comment: Actually, before you do anything, try to ping your raspberry pi `ping 192.168.0.32` And please post the `nmap` command that you used.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Ssh: No route to host](https://askubuntu.com/questions/754322/ssh-no-route-to-host)

Comment: See if [ubuntu server 18.04 ssh failure](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1167782/ubuntu-server-18-04-ssh-failure/1167818#1167818) helps